# Adding a Taskbar button ITaskbarList and detecting it being clicked

Tags: windows, winapi, win32com, win32gui

I’m looking to adding a “fake” button to the Windows taskbar that, when clicked, actually performs logic and activates a different window.

I want the behaviour to be familiar I.e.

- First button click brings the window to front
- Second click minimises
- Third click restores

I’ve tried creating an offscreen window and following its own events. But that has its own issues in that, due to other window activation, I won’t always be able to get the right behaviour or reliable sequence of events.

I’m looking to see if adding a custom button with ITaskbarList will work for me.

My question is, can I get some form of notification that the taskbar button has been clicked so I can perform my logic? I can’t see anything obvious in the docs.

Comment: You can add buttons to the toolbar control and receive WM_COMMAND in the owning window: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist3-thumbbaraddbuttons#remarks

Comment: reading the docs, this is more like adding buttons to the popup preview of a taskbar button.  For example play controls on a media player app.
I want to add the taskbar button itself and get notification of that button being clicked

Comment: `WM_COMMAND` applies to thumbnail buttons/previews. For the taskbar button itself, try `WM_ACTIVATE` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there is an exact match to what I need but I've managed to come up with a close match by having my window attached to my placeholder button permanently minimized and using WM_QUERYOPEN messages as a trigger.  Its not perfect in all situations but looks like its as close as I'm going to get.